# How to set a cookieflag store none for GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We are tracking our plugin which is loaded on iframe on client's websites. We are currently using storage none for cookie domain option on GTM to make it work. We couldn't get cookie domain option when we switch to GA4. It works on chrome, doesn't track on safari without storage none.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any luck? Also can you tell how you set `storage` as none for cookie domain option on GTM?